# EaselJS/CreateJS Sprite and Bitmap Color Key/set transparency color

Tags: android, transparent, createjs, easeljs, color-key

I was wondering if anyone knew how to set a transparency color and select a color to be replaced with another one for a sprite sheet and bitmaps using EaselJS.

I'm creating a JavaScript game where my characters need to be able to be color keyed for certain functionalities. I have found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427180/how-to-overlay-non-transparent-part-of-bitmap-with-a-color-in-easeljs-createjs) on Stackoverflow but I can't        quite understand it to work with what I need.

I really hope someone has answer, if you know of any other Canvas based classes that include this feature and could maybe work in relation with CreateJS that be great too. Thank you!

Comment: Can you indicate what is not clear about the filter? The filter example basically decides how to treat each pixel depending on its value. If you want to treat a specific color as alpha, then you would have to check pixels for that color, and change them to be transparent. Any more details to your question, or sample code that you have tried would be helpful.

Comment: I was trying to modify their code to make a specific color as alpha. That was the closest post to what I needed that's why I've linked it but it was making a mask and not setting it as alpha.

"If you want to treat a specific color as alpha, then you would have to check pixels for that color, and change them to be transparent." This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Does anyone have anyway to set a transparent color on a sprite sheet?